# Select first row after goup

Tags: mysql

I have the below query which return the name of a class which is less than 20 and if there is no class less than 20 it adds a new one. the problem is that when I delete a user from the class which was full than this query returns two row. 
I need to get only the first row that returns.

```
SELECT exam_venue AS venue 
  FROM application 
 WHERE class_level = 1 
   AND rownumber = 1
 GROUP 
    BY venue 
HAVING COUNT(id) < 20
```

Comment: This doesn't 'add' anything !?! See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

SELECT exam_venue AS venue FROM application WHERE class_level = 1 AND rownumber = 1
GROUP BY venue HAVING COUNT(id) < 20 LIMIT 0,1

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless.

Comment: I dont have the rownumber column therefore i get the error unknown column rownumber

Answer (score -1):

An easy way can be the following :::

```
SELECT TOP 1 exam_venue AS venue, COUNT(id)
FROM application 
WHERE class_level = 1 
GROUP BY venue 
HAVING COUNT(id) < 20
```

Comment: there is no row number column

Comment: as per your code snippet, i thought "rownumber" was a fieldname.
if its not, then remove that from "WHERE" Clause
@MuharremSmakiqi

Comment: even if i remove TOP 1 is not recognised

Comment: If youre using mysql, it should recognize TOP command.
btw, you should use an aggregate function with a GROUP BY clause.
you can try out the edited query. that should do. @MuharremSmakiqi